# jquery setting z-index before toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css

Tying to produce a proof of concept for a function, so ignore the terrible naming conventions! ;-)

I have a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Dde8d/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#commission_1').on('click', function () {
        var newZIndex = -1;
        if ($('#SearchForm_1').hasClass('showfrm')) {
            $('#SearchForm_1').css("z-index", newZIndex);
            /* Remove the comment below to make it work */
            /*$('#SearchForm_1').delay(750);*/
            /*it was chained on the line above */
        }
        $('#SearchForm_1').toggleClass("showfrm", 500, function () {
            if ($('#SearchForm_1').hasClass('showfrm')) {
                newZIndex = 100;
            }
            $('#srchText1').toggleClass("shrt", 500, function () {
                $('#commission_1').toggleClass("btn-success").toggleClass("btn-primary", 1000, function () {
                    $('#comm-icon-1').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-left");
                    $('#SearchForm_1').css("z-index", newZIndex);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The effect I am trying to achieve is:-
User pushes button, input form 'slides out' from behind button
User pushes button again, form 'slides back' behind button.

This fiddle is working, but only with a 750ms delay after changing the z index.

Why is this?  Is there a documented reason for z-index to not change immediately.

Note: I included JQuery UI to allow completion functions on toggleClass.  Could this have affected it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to have the input field come from behind, right away, just change your css transition settings from 1s to 0s (or whatever) also add z-index:-1; to make sure the input slides out from behind.

Comment: I'm confused why you'e changing the z-index, as far as I can see the form should always come from under the button, so why not just have the button with a higher z-index value than the form?

Comment: Setting the z-index of the form puts it behind the containing div... that's why I'm trying to change it in the first place!

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Dde8d/3/

Comment: Vickel, that is the effect I want, but the text box can only be selected on the bottom edge.  That's why I'm changing the z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.srchFrm {
     float: left;
     left: -87px;
     position: relative;
     top: -32px;
     z-index: -5;
}
.showfrm {
    left: 96px;
    margin: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: -32px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
    width: 300px;
 }
 .btn.btn-success {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
 }
 .search {
   background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   height: 51px;
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 4px 4px 4px 0;
   position: relative;
   transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
   width: 392px;
   z-index: 10;
}

 </style>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#commission_1').on('click', function () {
    $('#SearchForm_1').toggleClass("showfrm");
   });
  });

   </script>
   <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

     <div class="search">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="commission_1">Commission</button>
       <form action="#" name="SearchForm" method="get" id="SearchForm_1" class="srchFrm">
      <input type="text" name="s" maxlength="64" id="SearchForm" value="" class="text-comm-email" />
    <input type="button" value="Go" />
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is looking good, simpler form flow, but... it is only transitioning on the way out, how can I make it slide back?

Comment: Here is a link to my final version which is based from your version here http://jsfiddle.net/CeeBeeUK/Dde8d/6/ thanks fro putting me on the right path

Answer (score 0):

This might be a reflow issue. The reason for the delay working is that the page isn't re-rendered between the `z-index` update and the `.toggleClass()` call. Which it needs to be if the z-index is to take effect before the class is toggled.

You could change the `.delay()` to

```
$('#SearchForm_1').height();
```

The trick, and at the same time problem, with `height()` is that it always forces a reflow. It can be a problem because multiple, frequent reflows it can cause "layout thrashing". But in this case it's a useful trick, as the reflow will help set the `z-index`.

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't working http://jsfiddle.net/Dde8d/4/ .  It sounds like 'force reflow' should be my next google search.